# IOS how to compare date with another date?

Tags: ios, xml, compare, nsdate

I have a web service which contains a list of XML data. one of the element is `"UpdateTimeStampGMT"`. I have retrieve this parameter in this element already which looks like this when i log it out to do checking.

```
 UpdateTimestampGMT = "2015-11-03T01:00:59.503";
```

But the problem now is that i want to make use of this date to do a checking whether if this date is 4 days ago date or 3 days ago date, if it is valid i would like to retrieve other element in the block that falls under the correct date.

Here is the codings:

```
   int minusThreeDayopenSSLCount = 0;

    int bluecolor = 0;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *threeDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3*24*60*60];
//This is the data when i NSLOG threeDaysAgo: 2015-10-29 09:06:40 +0000

for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
        if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"] && [feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] isEqualToString:threeDaysAgo]) {
            minusThreeDayopenSSLCount ++;
        }
    }
 NSLog(@"-3 Total openSSLCount count is (green):  %d",minusThreeDayopenSSLCount);
```

When I `NSLOG`

the **minusThreeDayOpenSSLCount** it looks like this, which is not correct

> --> 2015-11-05 17:06:44.443 FYP_IOS_APP[928:444918] -3 Total openSSLCount count is (green):  0

When i change

```
if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"] && [feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] isEqualToString:threeDaysAgo]) {
//            minusThreeDayopenSSLCount++;
//        }
```

to

```
if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"] && [feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] isEqualToDate:[NSDate date]]) {
            openSSLCount++;
        }
```

it give me this error:

2015-11-05 17:38:08.138 FYP_IOS_APP[938:448845] -[__NSCFString isEqualToDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15cd90340
2015-11-05 17:38:08.139 IOS_APP[938:448845] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isEqualToDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15cd90340'

Comment: Your are comparing a `NSString *` with a `NSDate*`

Comment: How can it be done. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *threeDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3*24*60*60];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";

NSString *threeDaysAgoAsAString = [df stringFromDate:threeDaysAgo];

for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
  if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"] && [feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] isEqualToString:threeDaysAgoAsAString]) {
    minusThreeDayopenSSLCount ++;
  }
}
```

overall i do not think you should compare strings to check the equality of dates because that means that both date values have to be exactly the same (e.g. "2015-11-03T01:00:59.**503**" != "2015-11-03T01:00:59.**502**")...


**UPDATE**

try this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.day = -3; // days to subtract

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *threeDaysAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];

NSUInteger threeDaysAgoComparisonValue = [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:threeDaysAgo];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";

for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
  if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"]) {
    NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
    NSUInteger dateComparisonValue = [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:updateTimestampGMT];
    if (dateComparisonValue == threeDaysAgoComparisonValue) {
      minusThreeDayopenSSLCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

if you are targetting >= iOS 8 you can get the `threeDaysAgo` date even simpler:

```
NSDate *threeDaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-3 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

**HOPEFULLY FINAL EDIT :)**

```
NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *threeDaysAgo = [calender dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-3 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new]; // to create the dates in the for loop
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";

for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
  if ([feed[@"Classification"] isEqualToString:@"Activity Summary - OpenSSL \"HeartBleed\" Scanning"]) {
    NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
    if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:threeDaysAgo]) {
      minusThreeDayopenSSLCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, or do you have other approach to compare both dates? i just need to compare the dates thats all. no need to compare the time behind. Is there a Contain parameter for me to use to compare?

Comment: so let's say you have the 20th of august. three days ago it was the 17th of august. so the 17th of august, 00:01h would match and the 17th of august, 23:59h would also match?

Comment: yes, it will also match, i just want all the data from the day itself. the time doesn't matter

Comment: can you please show me how to do a contain for the dates? the above code you wrote is correct but still can't compare as like u said it wouldn't be equal to the time behind. please help.